# AngularJS and modularisation

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

AngularJs provides you the possibility to create modules. All fine. It also give you the power to add components to your modules like `service`, `controller`, etc...

My only problem with that is that no matter in what module did you define a component, from another module it can be entirely overwritten.

Examples:

```
app.module('aModule').controller('SimpleController', functino(){...});
app.module('bModule').controller('SimpleController', functino(){...});
```

If you try to define let's say a state definiction with `ui-router`, it will just won't work well, since one controller will completely overwrite the one loaded first.

Did you guys met with this problem too or it's just me?

Comment: nice question. Name space collision is a real problem for Angular 1 users. I am really curious in any efficient solution, other than "naming your components properly" ...

Answer (score 2):

no, that's normal behavior. You can namespace it like 'component.controller' (so do this in the name of the controller, not the module) which helps, other then that is not possible in Angular 1

Comment: nah, it won't help neither. It's just naming your modules but it won't have any affect on overwriting your controllers which has the same name.

Comment: he meant name controllers according the containing module.

Comment: I see, but I would not use this workaround. Would be a mess when trying injecting those services/values/etc..

Comment: fine, but that workaround is the only 'solution' as far as I know.